# Perceptron Classifier in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, perceptron

Im trying to figure out perceptron classifier algorithm.So as i research i create random problem like this.I want  to see the result on matlab.

For example i have  the energy values (1st feature) and zero-crossing numbers (2nd feature) for two classes
of sounds namely:

Class-1: Voiced sounds and

Class-2: Unvoiced sounds.

Voiced Sound Vectors:

```
 [16 4] , [11 6] , [13 8] , [21 7] , [16 6] , [19 9] , [21 5] , [26 6] , [22 10] , [24 8]
```

Unvoiced Sound Vectors:

```
[11 15] , [12 16] , [10 14] , [9 17] , [13 11] , [8 12] , [14 10] , [12 12] , [11 14] , [10 13]
```

And also weight vector is 1x20 vector

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

So how im gonna do this.

I´ve tried this which is close my problem but icant get it.

```
X=[0 0; 0 1; 1 1]
Y=[1 0; 2 1]
w=[1 1 1]
Result = perceptron( X, Y, w )

??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> perceptron at 15
            if sign(w'*X(:,ii)) ~= Y(ii) 

    Result = perceptron( X, Y, w' )

??? Error using ==> ne
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> perceptron at 19
        sum(sign(w'*X)~=Y) / size(X,2);
```

Comment: I get a "Too many parameter arguments." error message. But in my docs `perceptron(hardlimitTF,perceptronLF)` takes only two arguments (Matlab R2015b).

Comment: maybe i cant use weight vector.But how is gonna perceptron do learning thing without learning parameter

Comment: Transpose `w` into a column vector.